# Copy Cloud Storage File ( create a duplicate of the file )

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blob, google-cloud-storage

I have used https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/ to upload the file, and my files are getting stored on Google Cloud Storage, within a specified bucket.

**Structure**

I am storing the file in Cloud storage and keeping its `BlobKey` somewhere managed, when ever I need to serve it I use

```
BlobKey blobKey = service.createGsBlobKey(blobString);
service.serve(blobKey, response);
```

**My Requirement**

I am looking to give the user a function so the user can **create a copy of that file.** I am clueless about how this could be done. Will it help me if I am able to get raw `byte[]` and store back to cloud storage? The api does not seem to have such a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with the `GcsServiceFactory` class, as documented at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/GcsServiceFactory , and call one of its static method overloads of `createGcsService` to obtain an instance of interface `GcsService`, which, in turn, is documented at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/GcsService .

The latter's method `copy`, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/GcsService#copy(com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFilename, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFilename) , is the one you're looking for.

`GcsFilename`, two instances of which you need to pass to the `copy` method, is documented at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/GcsFilename -- it's really simple though, as you can see from its constructor:

```
GcsFilename(java.lang.String bucketName, java.lang.String objectName)
```

so essentially it's just the bucket name and the object name within it.